# Good F# Asynchronous IO Sample

Tags: f#, asynchronous, io

Where can I find a good sample of Asynchronous IO on files with thread hooping?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this video cast http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/ Luca Bolognese explain F#, including async file reading and parallel map reduce.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: [Using F# Asynchronous Workflows to simplify concurrent programming in AutoCAD](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/01/harnessing-f-as.html).